# Angular - Run ngAfterViewInit() code only after Inputs() are initialized

Tags: angular, typescript

I Have some code in ngAfterViewInit() in a component:

```
  @Input 
  public stringArray: string[];
  public newArray: string[];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.newArray = this.stringArray.filter(x => x.includes('a'));
  }
```

I put the code in ngAfterViewInit() to wait for @Input properties to initialize.

However, it looks like the code in ngAfterViewInit() is 'undefined' when execution gets to it.

How do I get all the @Input properties to initialize before running the `filter()` operation?

**EDIT:** The @Input property does have data later. It just happens after ngAfterViewInit(). How do I make sure my code runs only after all @Input() properties are initialized?

Comment: your code is fine, just check my solution below. and issue will be resolved.

Comment: This is a typio. stringArray is array not function. Dont put ()

Comment: @james remove parenthesis with stringArray in viewinit.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to ng on changes.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes && changes.stringArray.currentValue && !this.newArray) {
       this.newArray = this.stringArray.filter(x => x.includes('a'));
    }
  }
```

because your property was changing parent even after initialization of your child component.

Comment: ^I already have this code in my original post. And `filter()` is a javascript method you can run on arrays.

Comment: @JamesBurani, no you were using stringArray as method when its property. believe me. try this.

Comment: Oh right, my bad. I fixed it. However, that was not the issue. I still have the same problem.

Comment: try the changed solution above.

Answer (score 0):

in parent component use

```
<div *ngIf='stringArray.length >0'>
<child-component [stringArray]='stringArray' ></child-component>
</div>
```

i.e your child component is initializes only if there is data in your input properties

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use setter and ignore the `ngAfterViewInit()`.

```js
public newArray: string[];

@Input
set stringArray(value: any) {
  this.newArray = value.filter(x => x.includes('a'));
}
```

Comment: Tried that, no dice.

Comment: Can you show the parent template? How is the value bound to `stringArray` input? I've also edited my answer to apply the filter to the `value` variable. See if it works for you.